# Saving Every new String in to an array in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm trying to save every new string that i receive (result) from an input into an array in local storage, to use it later

```
                $('.crearGpo').on('click',function() {
            bootbox.prompt("Name of the Gr", function(result ,e) {

                if(result != null && result !="" )
                {

                    names = [];
                    names[0]= result;
                    localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(names);
                    var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);
                    console.log(storedNames);
                    localStorage.setItem('name', result);
                    name = localStorage.getItem('name');

                   $('.top-card-grupos ul ').last().append("<li><button class=\"btn\" id=\""+name+"\">"+name+"</button></li>");


                }



            });
        });
```

But is just saving the last string, not every string that i receive, any help would be great

Comment: that's because every time the click handler is called you make a new **names** array. Move that array outside the click handler and use **names.push** to add more items to it on every click instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new array for each result, and not incrementing the array index each time you assign a value to it, meaning each value will be overwritten. Try:

```
names = []; //Array for all results
var count = 0; //Keep track of the number of results

if(result != null && result !="" )
            {

                names[count++]= result; //Store and increment counter
                localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(names);
                var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);
                console.log(storedNames);
                localStorage.setItem('name', result);
                name = localStorage.getItem('name');

               $('.top-card-grupos ul ').last().append("<li><button class=\"btn\" id=\""+name+"\">"+name+"</button></li>");


            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i was going crazy with this

Comment: Not a problem! The others are right - [JavaScript Array Push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) method achieves the same effect as recording/incrementing the counter value

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array on every click. You should create it once and push values into it on every click instead.

Like this:

```js
var names = []; // create the array once
$('.crearGpo').on('click', function() {
  bootbox.prompt("Name of the Gr", function(result, e) {

    if (result != null && result != "") {


      names.push(result); //add the result to the names array
      localStorage["names"] = JSON.stringify(names);
      var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage["names"]);
      console.log(storedNames);
      localStorage.setItem('name', result);
      name = localStorage.getItem('name');

      $('.top-card-grupos ul ').last().append("<li><button class=\"btn\" id=\"" + name + "\">" + name + "</button></li>");


    }
  });
});
```